# Using user defined runtime attributes let the app crash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I created a custom UIControl which will be used in different places on the app with changing its background in each place, so i figure out that i should "user defined runtime attributes" on the storyboard to not copy the duplicate the code, but the problem is the app crash each time i try to run it. I am using XCode 4.6.3.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aEiO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdGuX.png

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key toggleType.

Comment: Check your toggleType outlet, it's not linked properly.

Comment: I just figure out how to solve the problem by overiding the method **- setValue:forKey:** and get the key that you've entered on the list in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are describing is almost always related to a problem in interface-builder links. Go over the outlets and make sure that they are all linked to their respective object. Hunch: toggleType has a defined link but isn't defined in the class code. If you view the links in the storyboard, it will have a yellow warning sign next to it (right click on file's owner to inspect all relations).